# How to find what SSL/TLS version is used in Java

Tags: java, ssl

I have a java based client (using java 1.6.30) that opens an SSL connection to my server deployed on Tomcat 7.0.26. Tomcat is using Java 6 and in the server.xml I configured the connector to use `sslProtocol="TLS"`.

I wonder what is the SSL version being used? Is it TLS1.0? TLS1.1? Something else?

Answer (score 36):

Get the [`SSLSession`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSession.html) from your `SSLSocket` on your client and use its `getProtocol()` method.

[Oracle JRE/OpenJDK 6 supports SSLv3 and TLS 1.0](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunJSSEProvider). You would need at least the [IBM JRE 6/7](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_6.0.0/com.ibm.java.security.component.60.doc/security-component/jsse2Docs/protocols.html) or [Oracle JRE/OpenJDK 7 to get support for TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunJSSEProvider). (This is also related to the available cipher suites, as mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10488029/372643).)

Comment: Oracle Java 6 suports TLS 1.1 (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#SSLContext)

Comment: Hm.. on the other hand here oracle tells that TLS 1.1 is not supported in Java 6 https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/diagnosing_tls_ssl_and_https

Comment: @emstol The [Standard Names](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#SSLContext) document is just about the official names (essentially, it's planned in advance). Oracle's [SunJSSE provider (the one that's shipped with the "normal" Oracle JRE)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunJSSEProvider) doesn't not support TLS 1.1 in Oracle JRE 6.

Comment: There is support for TLS 1.1 since [JDK 6u111](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview-156328.html). But it is a paid update - not freely available.

Comment: And to add, since I ended up here also looking, [JDK 6u121](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview-156328.html#R160_121) added support for tls 1.2 client connections.

Answer (score 21):

You can use the following snippet to get an array of the supported protocols:

```
SSLContext.getDefault().getSupportedSSLParameters().getProtocols()
```

If you want it as a whitespace delimited string, e.g. for SMTP negotiation, pass the array to String.join(), i.e.:

```
String.join(" ", SSLContext.getDefault().getSupportedSSLParameters().getProtocols())
```

The latter snippet shows in Java 8 on Windows:

> SSLv2Hello SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2

And in Java 11 on Windows:

> TLSv1.3 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1 SSLv3 SSLv2Hello

Comment: Supported protocols >= enabled protocols >= the actual protocol used for the connection.

Comment: Is there is a way know supported TLS/SSL  protocol version for JDK 5?

Answer (score 9):

This gets the active protocols:

```
  private static String getActiveProtocols() {
    try {
      return Arrays.toString(SSLContext.getDefault().createSSLEngine().getEnabledProtocols());
    } catch (Exception e) {
      StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
      e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(stringWriter));
      return "Unable to get enabled protocols: " + e.getMessage() + LINE_SEPARATOR + stringWriter;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Great answer!
Works down to Java 5, where static imports (needed for `LINE_SEPARATOR`) and `Arrays.toString()` were added.
But you could have mentioned wether you got inspired by other answers in this question or not, and linked them if it's the case.

Comment: This worked for me better than eg. isapir's answer where for some reason eg. Temurin 1.8.0_322 did return TLSv1.3 but actually did not work. This code did not return TLSv1.3 as 'supported' for exact same java version, and thus worked for me better.

Answer (score 3):

for tomcat 8.5.38 and 8.5.46 (and probably tomcat 7.0x and newer) adding this to the AccessLogValve pattern (in server.xml) - and enabling that Valve - will show the TLS version in use:

```
%{org.apache.tomcat.util.net.secure_protocol_version}r

eg
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" %{org.apache.tomcat.util.net.secure_protocol_version}r />
```

Comment: Edit request queue is full, but there's a misplaced " here.  The %{org.apache.tomcat.util.net.secure_protocol_version}r part should be inside the pattern="" instead of after.