# SSLSocket used ciphersuite

Tags: java, ssl, encryption, https

To understand better the TLS mechanism. **I would like to get what is the ciphersuite my server and each of its clients agreed to use after the handshake**. However, I cannot find any methods or any information on the web to do this.

I have I Java server and access to the SSLSockets.

How would you suggest to do it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is more or less the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10500665/372643), but for the cipher suite: use `getSession()` on your `SSLSocket` (or `SSLEngine`) to get the current `SSLSession`, then use [`getCipherSuite()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSession.html#getCipherSuite%28%29).

(Note that `getSession()` will have the side effect of initiating a handshake if this hasn't already been done another way, see [introduction of `SSLSocket` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html)).

Comment: Really sorry for bothering about that. It was so obvious! Thanks!