# Impact on Java clients due to disabling SSL 3.0 encryption in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce

We are connecting to Salesforce from the Java client using Force.com Web Services Connector. In November and December 2014 Salesforce will be disabling SSL 3.0 encryption in stages to prevent it from being used to access the Salesforce platform. Will it impact the Java application integrating with Force.com APIs?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what version of Java you're using. [1.6 and up support at least TLS 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10500511/how-to-find-what-ssl-tls-version-is-used-in-java). You can double check by capturing the initial connection exchnages with [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/), it'll show you what the client & server say they support, and what the final negotiated protocol was.

Comment: We are using Java  1.5 version (jdk1.5.0_22)