# SSL handshaking is not working in 64 bit product same thing is working fine 32 bit product

Tags: ssl, tomcat6

In my environment I am using tomcat 6 and jdk 1.6.

My ssl conection settings (from server.xml) is:

```
<Connector SSLEnabled="true" acceptCount="100" ciphers="TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA" clientAuth="false" connectionTimeout="20000" debug="0" disableUploadTimeout="true" enableLookups="false" keystoreFile="./conf/server.keystore" keystorePass="******" maxSpareThreads="75" maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" name="SSL" port="8887" scheme="https" secure="true" sslProtocol="TLS" sslProtocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2"/>
```

same connection is working fine in 32 bit product, but it is not working for 64bit.

I tried openssl to find the reason it is throwing exception like:

> verify return:1 10100:error:14094438:SSL
>   routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:tlsv1 alert internal
>   error:.\ssl\s3_pkt.c:1275:SSL alert number 80 10100:error:140790E5:SSL
>   routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:.\ssl\s23_lib.c:177:

total print from opensll command check the images 64-Bit, 32-Bit[image: 64 bit]

[image: 32 bit]

Comment: FYI: Java 6 supports TLSv1 only, see [How to find what SSL/TLS version is used in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10500665/1606632).

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it, some jar files are missing from my jre folder, after replacing them it's working fine. Thank you all.