# Find TLS protocol version in JDK8

Tags: java

I am using **JDK8** and I know the default **TLS** version is 1.2, but how can I find it out from program once I open the connection?
Is there any method in `javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection` that gives the **TLS** version or any other way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find what SSL/TLS version is used in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10500511/how-to-find-what-ssl-tls-version-is-used-in-java)

Comment: @Michu93 I am not using any server. Just a standalone program using JDK8 to open a connection and trying to figure out TLS version.

Comment: There no such method, but you can supply custom SSLSocketFactory, which you can use for tracking the negotiated tls version