# Java sockets: How to know which version of TLS my SslSocket is currently using?

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, tls1.2

My client dials a server. We've recently adopted a security policy to allow only TLS 1.2 connections but we are being soft with the transition: If the server and client cannot agree on a TLS 1.2 socket, then some warning is raised for this issue to be fixed but connection should proceed as normal.

So, I am not really looking for a way to enforce my client to only create TLS 1.2 connection but a way to know which one is currently used.

My question is about how to get that information from the live socket.

Here's how my client creates sockets:

```
public static SSLSocket getSSLsocket (String hostFQDN, int port, String ksFullPath, String ksPassword, String pkPassword) {
    try {
        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        KeyManagerFactory keyMngFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");

        keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(ksFullPath), ksPassword.toCharArray());
        keyMngFactory.init(keyStore, pkPassword.toCharArray());
        context.init(keyMngFactory.getKeyManagers(), null, null);
        //TODO: We are going to need a truststore definition... Meanwhile: System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "src/resources/certificates/epp/cacertsuk");
        SSLSocketFactory sslScktFactory = context.getSocketFactory();
        return (SSLSocket) sslScktFactory.createSocket(hostFQDN, port);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not create SSL socket", e);
    }
}
```

I am aware of this question: [How to find what SSL/TLS version is used in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10500511/how-to-find-what-ssl-tls-version-is-used-in-java) , where the leading answer seems to say I can get the SSLSession from the SSLSocket and then call .getProtocol... But an example on how to do this was not provided and I was unable to find the solution myself

Comment: Well... That question has, as an answer, a reference to the same question I referred to. The code is lacking. Although, I must admit it's not a lot of code lacking :)

Answer (score 1):

My problem is because above this class, I am using socket as a generic object, which could be plaintext or SSL. So, when I try to do `socket.getSession` I don't see that method.

So far, I am doing:

```
public String getTls () {
    SSLSocket temporaryReference = (SSLSocket) socket;
    SSLSession sslSession = temporaryReference.getSession();
    return sslSession.getProtocol();
}
```

And I am getting:

```
TLSv1.2
```