# How to get SSLParameters JDK 1.5

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-6, java-5

I have written code in JDK 1.6

```
SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
        SSLParameters params = context.getSupportedSSLParameters();
        List<String> enabledCiphers = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String cipher : params.getCipherSuites()) {
            boolean exclude = false;
            if (exludedCipherSuites != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < exludedCipherSuites.length && !exclude; i++) {
                    exclude = cipher.indexOf(exludedCipherSuites[i]) >= 0;
                }
            }
            if (!exclude) {
                enabledCiphers.add(cipher);
            }
        }
        String[] cArray = new String[enabledCiphers.size()];



        SSLSocketFactory sf = context.getSocketFactory();
        sf = new DOSSLSocketFactory(sf, cArray);
        urlConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(sf);
```

The problem is that, in JDK 1.5 I do not have SSLParameters. How can I solve the problem in JDK 1.5?

Comment: You have to do it on the SSLSocketFactory instead of the SSLContext.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the supported cipher suites you could use [SSLSocketFactory.getSupportedCipherSuites()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocketFactory.html#getSupportedCipherSuites%28%29). See [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487962/java-cipher-suites).